# Returning sum of given integer n. (Range(1,n+1)) in constant time

Tags: python, sum

We get an input of a positive integer n, and I am supposed to return the sum from 1 to n (including n).

We have to complete the task in a constant time. I have a solution, and I thought it is in constant time, but the tests of the site tells me that I fail. Is my solution not constant?

My solution:

```
n = int(input())
print(int(n*(n+1)/2))
```

Comment: It looks like constant time to me. What tests fail, and what's the reason given? Do they *all* fail? Maybe you're not reading input the way the test harness wants you to.

Comment: The advice to use `//` is good, but in fact dividing an integer by 2 produces an exact result in floating point.  There should be no inaccuracy possible.

Comment: Its fixed!
I removed the cast in the print and put // instead of /.
Thank u guys!

The task was that it is compiled in a time they set and it seems like the way i did it went over the time.

I was stuck on this for an hour and tried all kind of things...

Is it possible to set it as answered? Im quite new here.

Comment: Changing `/` to `//` won't make an appreciable time difference. I'm doubtful that's the reason your program started passing the tests. Unless you want to share more details I don't think this question is particularly useful to others; you can delete it.

Comment: Im for real. Thats all i changed.
Try it yourself :  https://the-morpheus.cc/challenges/intro/time_limit

The constant part always failed.

Comment: @TimRoberts You're assuming that the result is small enough to be representable by a float.

Answer (score 0):

Your solution is mathematically valid and should run in constant time. I recommend that you use int division `//` instead of float division, since floats have a limited range that might cause results to be inaccurate.

```
n = int(input())
print(n*(n+1)//2)
```